# Why do I get this timeout error with this JEST test in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jestjs

I am running some tests to test an API. The first two tests run fine, but the last gives me a Timeout Error. Increasing the Timeout to 30s does not work.
The code runs fine in Postman, and I get the 404 error when I put in the incorrect id.

If I change tourId in `const tourId = 'invalid-user-id';` to the correct Id, the test runs without any timeout.

Any suggestions about the reason for the timeout error?

Thanks in advance.

```
import supertest from 'supertest';
    import app from '../app';
    import dotenv from 'dotenv';
    import mongoose from 'mongoose';

    dotenv.config({ path: `${__dirname}/../../config.env` });

    let DB = '';
    if (process.env.DATABASE && process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD) {
      DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace(
        '<PASSWORD>',
        process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
      );
    }

    /* Connecting to the database before each test. */
    mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

    beforeEach(async () => {
      await mongoose.connect(DB);
    });

    afterEach(async () => {
      await mongoose.connection.close();
    });


    describe('tours', () => {
      describe('get tours', () => {
        describe('given the tours does exist', () => {
          it('should return a 200', async () => {
            const res = await supertest(app).get('/api/v1/tours');
            expect(res.status).toBe(200);
          });
        });
      });
    });

    describe('tour', () => {
      describe('get tour', () => {
        describe('given the tour does exist', () => {
          it('should return a 200', async () => {
            const tourId = '5c88fa8cf4afda39709c296c';
            const res = await supertest(app).get(`/api/v1/tours/${tourId}`);
            expect(res.status).toBe(200);
          });
        });
      });
    });

    describe('tour', () => {
      describe('get tour', () => {
        describe('given the tour does not exist', () => {
          it('should return a 404', async () => {
            const tourId = 'invalid-user-id';
            const res = await supertest(app).get(`/api/v1/tours/${tourId}`);
            console.log(res);
            expect(res.status).toBe(404);
          });
        });
      });
    });


//This is my handler function 

export const getOne = (Model: Model<any>, popOptions?: popOptionsType) =>
  catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    let query = Model.findById(req.params.id);
    if (popOptions) query = query.populate(popOptions);
    const doc = await query;
    if (!doc) {
      return next(new AppError('No document found with that ID ', 404));
    }
    res.status(200).json({ status: 'success', results: doc });
  });
```

I think I am getting the error when the error is going through this error handler.

```
class AppError extends Error {
  status: string;
  statusCode: number;
  isOperational: boolean;
  constructor(message: string, statusCode: number) {
    super(message); //Message is the parameter built in Error accept
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.status = `${statusCode}`.startsWith('4') ? 'fail' : 'error';
    this.isOperational = true;
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor); //When a new object is created constructor function is called and that constructor will not appear in the stack trace
  }
}

export default AppError;
```

Comment: use `try {...} catch(error){expect(error.status).toBe(404)}` || `statusCode`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am still getting the Timeout error with the above code.

Comment: inside the `try{}`, you should also `throw new Err..) following handler function. it would be like: ``` {
    const tourId = "invalid-user-id";
    await supertest(app).get(`/api/v1/tours/${tourId}`);
    throw new Error({msg: 'tst', statusCode: 404})
  } catch (error) {
    expect(error.statusCode).toBe(404);
  }```

Comment: What happens with `const tourId = 'invalidUserId';`?

Comment: Getting a timeout error, and the test is failing.